# Sharepoint logging software

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, logging

I'm looking for a way to improve upon the SharePoint 2010 logging capabilities, in order to show more detail about who changed what, and when, from a structural perspective, specifically.

I did an exercise whereby a couple of us logged into a SharePoint 2010 tenant and made some structural changes over a 60 minute period. Here's an example of some of the things we did, and the corresponding SharePoint log records:

1. Deleted list column (SP logged "Update - Schema change")
2. Created a new view (nothing logged)
3. Set "requires content approval" to "yes" on a library (SP logged "Update")
4. Added a site column (SP logged "Update - Schema change")

I'm not sure if I can improve upon the logging (OOB) to be more specific (and what this may do to performance if I can?). We have about 200 SP tenants split across a couple of farms, all hosted on MS Azure.

Alternatively, would anyone be able to recommend third party software? The software I've found to date is more concerned with content updates while I'm needing structural/schema information.

It may be worth mentioning that we will be upgrading to SP 2013 at some point next year.

TIA for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll be out of luck as actions #1 and #2 are not logged within SharePoint's own code (so not captured in Site Collection Audit logging nor the Event Cache). Since any 3rd party software which compiles with Microsoft's approach of using SharePoint provided-APIs, no supportable solution would be able to offer you any further audit actions besides what is delivered out of the box.